# how to connect provider via Metamask?

Tags: provider, metamask, ether

I am working on a project, i need to connect provider via MetaMask, need help regarding this.
const providerrinkeby = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
i tried this code but this is not working. I need to connect provider via Metamask.
thanks,

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
     const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum, "any");
     const signer = provider.getSigner();
     const iface = new ethers.utils.Interface(this.getABI());
    
      const tx = {
                to: this.contractAddress,
                gasPrice: this.gasPrice,
                gasLimit: this.gasLimit,
                data: iface.encodeFunctionData("send(address,string)", [
                    this.address, "hello"
                ])
            };

      signer.sendTransaction(tx)
            .then(() => console.log("%c tx was sent", "color: #009900"))
            .catch(() => console.log("%c tx wasn't sent", "color: #FF0000"));
```